# Goerli Smart Contract Deployment taking way too long because of pending transactions

Tags: contract-deployment, infura, alchemy

My deployments are very slow. I've read that I need to override pending transactions by resetting the nonce. I'm using Infura. Is there a way to view pending transactions and their nonce like I would on alchemy?

Also, would this problem have anything to do with the influx of people moving onto the Goerli testnet after the merge?

Answer (score 0):

You can check your pending transaction on your metamask and can resolve this issue by sending another transaction on the same nonce with higher gas fees .Yes you are right after the merge the traffice on goerli has been high . So i suggest to test your contracts on Sepolia or Mumbai